Twitter Oauth 2.0 permission scope configuration in auth.js or next-auth only getting users.read tweet.read offline.access scope
What ever scope i Give i only get users.read tweet.read offline.access scope like this url from twitter https://x.com/i/oauth2/authorize?scope=users.read+tweet.read+offline.access.
This is my code I have check https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4251 and try to implement according to it but it doesn't work. whatever i do only three scope is available.
import TwitterProvider from 'next-auth/providers/twitter';
export const config = {
  debug: true,
  pages: {
    signIn: '/sign-up',
  },
  providers: [
    TwitterProvider({
      //@ts-ignore
      version: '2.0', // opt-in to Twitter OAuth 2.0
      authorization: {
        url: 'https://x.com/i/oauth2/authorize',
        params: {
          scope: 'users.read tweet.read tweet.write offline.access',
        },
      profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.data.id,
          name: profile.data.name,
          image: profile.data.profile_image_url,
          email: profile.data.email,
          username: profile.data.username,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],



I also face this problem and when I see twitter.js file inside node_modules of auth.js find out authorization URL is hard coded with this URL string https://x.com/i/oauth2/authorize?scope=users.read tweet.read offline.access
To fix it follow following step follow by me.
For youtube video reference

change the twitter.js file  by the scope you want to add mine was https://x.com/i/oauth2/authorize?scope=tweet.read tweet.write users.read like.write like.read list.read list.write offline.access.
as you have change inside node_modules which is inside .gitignore file we need to patch the auth.js package.
install patch-package using npm i patch-package and run command npx patch-package @auth/core.
delete node_modules and at package.json add postinstall command ⇒  "postinstall": "patch-package".
install node_modules and run it will work.


Thank you so much it really work for me. Thank you for detail video
